# Having trouble with a frequency table in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create a frequency table for how many times a word appears in a sentence. I was trying to accomplish this with 2 arrays but every time I trace it, the words will not go into the frequency tables.

```
 boolean found = false;
                for (int y = 0; y < numWordsInArray; y++)
                {

                    found = arrayOfWords[y].equals(word);
                    if(found)
                    {
                        numTimesAppeared[y]++; 

                    }
                    if (!found)   //it's not already found
                    {
                        //add the word to the array of words
                        arrayOfWords[numWordsInArray] = word; 
                        numWordsInArray++; 

                    }
                }
```

and when I run this loop:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(arrayOfWords[x]);
    }
```

to trace the array, I get output of 10 spaces.

link to the whole program : http://pastebin.com/F4t6yCkD

Comment: So where exactly do you update the variable `word`?

Comment: How big is arrayOfWords? are you sure is ok to increase numWordsInArray value? You may be mixing `y` and `numWordsInArray`.

Comment: where do you initialize numWordsInArray and the arrayOfWords array.

Comment: The program is a text analyzer so its hard to explain in snippets, The program itself is pretty short: http://pastebin.com/F4t6yCkD

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap` instead of the array `numTimesAppeared`.
Sample code:

```
private Map<String, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public void statFreq(String[] words) {

    for(String word : words) {
        Integer freq = freqMap.get(word);
        if(freq == null) {
            freqMap.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            freqMap.put(word, freq + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a hashtable instead

```
 Hashtable<String, Integer> words = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
```

using

```
 Integer count = words.get (word)
```

and

```
 if (count == null) {
     words.put (word, 1);
 else
     words.put (word, count.intValue () + 1);
```